# How can I add HTML formatting to 'Swift Mail tutorial based' PHP email?

Tags: php, html, email

I have developed a competition page for a client, and they wish for the email the customer receives be more than simply text. The tutorial I used only provided simple text, within the 'send body message'. I am required to add html to thank the customer for entering, with introducing images to this email.

The code is:

```
//send the welcome letter
function send_email($info){

    //format each email
    $body = format_email($info,'html');
    $body_plain_txt = format_email($info,'txt');

    //setup the mailer
    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
    $message ->setSubject('Thanks for entering the competition');
    $message ->setFrom(array('info@examplemail.com' => 'FromEmailExample'));
    $message ->setTo(array($info['email'] => $info['name']));

    $message ->setBody('Thanks for entering the competition, we will be in touch if you are a lucky winner.');

    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    return $result;

}
```

This function.php sheet is working and the customer is recieving their email ok, I just need to change the

> ('Thanks for entering the competition,
>   we will be in touch if you are a lucky
>   winner.')

to have HTML instead...

Please, if you can, provide me with an example of how I can integrate HTML into this function.

Answer (score 5):

You can also just add **'text/html'** to setBody ([ref](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html)):

```
->setBody($this->renderView('YouBundleName:Default:email.html.twig'), 'text/html');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setContentType('text=html');
```

Comment: Hi Galen, thanks for your fast reply, I'm unsure where I should insert this? Should I remove any lines and replace them with your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Will the same text remain or should it be styled somehow?
Editing your emails in html requires inline css styles eg:

```
('<p style="font-size:1.2em; color:#f0f0f0;">Thanks for entering the competition, we will be in touch if you are a lucky winner.</p>')
```

if you need a table just add:

```
('<table style="font-size:1.2em; color:#f0f0f0;"><tr><td>Thanks for entering the competition, we will be in touch if you are a lucky winner.</td></tr></table>')
```

or to make it more simpler

```
$message_body'
<table style="font-size:1.2em; color:#f0f0f0;">
<tr>
<td>Thanks for entering the competition, we will be in touch if you are a lucky winner.</td>
</tr>
</table>
';

$message ->setBody($message_body);
```

I know that when I need to send html emails I need to set the content-type to html which I believe you did on the following line

```
$body = format_email($info,'html');
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. if not let me know

Comment: Hi Krike,

Thanks for getting back to me, I have tried this method of typing in the table code to the function, and basically the email I recieve then shows me the tags, instead of using the tags to style the text?? Do you know any other way around this?

Comment: It's OK, I got it working. Thanks a lot for your help Krike. :-)

Comment: Glad you could make it work, i thought the content type was allready set to html but I guess it was not seeing galens reply.